# How to read SMS from GSM Modem using AT and AT+ commands in php?

Tags: php, wamp, communication, gsm, modem

I want to read SMS received on a SIM.
SIM is inserted into GSM modem, modem is connected to my local machine using USB port.

I am using wamp on windows

After reading SMS I wan't to check whether SMS content has specific word, if yes I want to call one API. I can achieve this once I am able to read the SMS.

Also I will be scheduling this script, as I have to keep reading SMS 24X7.

Is there any library or script available for this?

Comment: Why don't you make it easier on yourself and get something like Twilio set up?

Comment: Well, I have gone through Twilio, but it doesn't fullfill all my requirements. Can I call my own API after reading SMS? Also there are no proper details about pricing.

Comment: Are we talking about the same Twilio? Pricing is very clear on their website - https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing. Inbound messages go to your server, where you can process and act on them. It fulfills all of your stated requirements.

Comment: Pricing that they have shown is to SEND sms. I simply want to read SMS and call my own API. I also contacted Twilio stating my requirements. Here is their reply..
`Thanks for writing into us here at Twilio. This is something you would have to build out with your own application that the Twilio API in integrated into. But once you build this functionality it should be possible.`

Comment: Right next to the send pricing is the receive pricing. It's right there on that page. You'd have to write the code to process the incoming message, as Twilio stated, but that's the case whatever you choose. No one else is going to write your code.

Comment: Ok. I am from INDIA, For INDIA, they have mentioned pricing only for sending SMS, not receiving. And I assumed, they provide a solution to read SMS and call API using some cPanel etc. Fine, I will drop idea of using Twilio for time being. I have created C# windows service which reads SMS, calls API and also replies back with SMS (using SMS Gateway API).

Answer (score 0):

You can install and make a simple config for [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) Then use it's API or db to read incoming SMS

But it's not an easy job

Comment: Isn't there a library/script, which does this easily?

Comment: Not sure there is. Especially in php. In case your mobile operator supports sms-to-email you can receive e-mail with your messages using php and process your messages, use 3rd APIs and so on.